# Estender classe TClientSocket Delphi

Tags: delphi, socket, classes

Gostaria de saber como Estender a classe TClientSocket em Delphi, para colocar novas funcionalidades sem perder as antigas, com exemplos. Abraço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta informar a classe que está querendo estender entre parênteses depois do **class**

```
unit ClientSocketPersonalizada

uses
  System.Win.ScktComp;

type
  TClientSocketPersonalizada = class(TClientSocket)
  public
    procedure SeuMetodo;
  end;
```

Comment: Obrigado, realmente estava em duvida se estava fazendo corretamente.